# Hard disk problems in guest (not host) cause VirtualBox guest to get stuck

Tags: virtualbox

I started using VirtualBox on a new host.
For the second time, one of the guest instances gets stuck.
After I restart it (which necessitated `kill -1` of its process), I see the below lines in its syslog:

```
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/10:80:20:11:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq 8192 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/10:88:40:11:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq 8192 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/10:90:60:11:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq 8192 out#012         res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/10:98:90:11:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 19 ncq 8192 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/20:a0:d0:11:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 20 ncq 16384 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/20:a8:00:12:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 21 ncq 16384 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/20:b0:40:12:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 22 ncq 16384 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/10:b8:70:12:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq 8192 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/10:c0:a0:12:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq 8192 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/10:c8:d0:12:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 25 ncq 8192 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/20:d0:f0:12:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 26 ncq 16384 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/10:d8:10:0d:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 27 ncq 8192 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/10:e0:e0:0c:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 28 ncq 8192 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/10:e8:20:13:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 29 ncq 8192 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: cmd 61/10:f0:50:0d:b8/00:00:17:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq 8192 out#012         res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4.00: status: { DRDY }
Nov  5 21:46:25 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4: hard resetting link
Nov  5 21:46:28 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
Nov  5 21:46:33 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4: hard resetting link
Nov  5 21:46:35 insert-test-virtualbox kernel: ata4: SATA link down (SStatus 1 SControl 300)
```

The VirtualBox host shows no indications of any problems relating to VirtualBox or hard-disk (actually, the host's `/var/log/messages` show no errors whatsoever).
Googling, I found similar issues reported for non-virtual machines, but no real directions on how to resolve the issue when it appears in a VirtualBox guest.
**Any ideas on how to resolve the above?**

*Versions:*

- VirtualBox: 5.2.20r125813
- Guest: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)
- Host: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

Comment: [This bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8311) suggests changing your disks from dynamic to a fixed size may fix the issue.

Comment: Is the virtual host have enough CPU and I/O bandwidth on the host to properly execute?  This might not be a problem with the VM but the host where it is being run on.  Of course, your VM itself could be hosed requiring a reinstall.

Comment: Thanks, @yoonix, I'll try with a static disk, and see if the problem disappears.

Comment: The host has ample resorces free, and, as I mentioned, the host /var/log/messages show no problems.